# HAProxy + NodeJS gets stuck on TCP Retransmission

Tags: tcp, haproxy, node.js

I have a HAProxy + NodeJS + Rails Setup, I use the NodeJS Server for file upload purposes.

The problem I'm facing is that if I'm uploading through haproxy to nodejs and a "TCP (Fast) Retransmission" occurs because of a lost packet the TX rate on the client drops to zero for about 5-10 secs and gets flooded with TCP Retransmissions.

This does not occur if I upload to NodeJS directly (TCP Retransmission happens too but it doesn't get stuck with dozens of retransmission attempts).

My test setup is a simple HTML4 FORM (method POST) with a single file input field.
The NodeJS Server only reads the incoming data and does nothing else.

I've tested this on multiple machines, networks, browsers, always the same issue.

Here's a TCP Traffic Dump from the client while uploading a file:

```
.....
TCP 1506    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
>> everything is uploading fine until:
TCP 1506    [TCP Fast Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
TCP 66      [TCP Dup ACK 7392#1] 63265 > http [ACK] Seq=4844161 Ack=1 Win=524280 Len=0 TSval=657047088 TSecr=79373730
TCP 1506    [TCP Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
>> the last message is repeated about 50 times for >>5-10 secs<< (TX drops to 0 on client, RX drops to 0 on server)
TCP 1506    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
>> upload continues until the next TCP Fast Retransmission and the same thing happens again
```

The haproxy.conf (haproxy v1.4.18 stable) is the following:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 debug
    maxconn     4096 # Total Max Connections. This is dependent on ulimit
    nbproc      2

defaults
    log global
    mode        http
    option      httplog
    option      tcplog

frontend http-in
    bind *:80

    timeout client 6000

    acl is_websocket   path_beg /node/

    use_backend node_backend  if is_websocket

    default_backend app_backend

# Rails Server (via nginx+passenger)
backend app_backend
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor

    timeout server 30000
    timeout connect 4000
    server app1 127.0.0.1:3000

# node.js
backend node_backend
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /node/(.*)     \1\ /\2
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    timeout queue 5000
    timeout server 6000
    timeout connect 5000
    server node1 127.0.0.1:3200 weight 1 maxconn 4096
```

Thanks for reading! :)

Simon

Comment: What sort of firewall are you using?  Have you tried disabling it temporarily to see if the issues persist?  Are you seeing packet loss to your server's gateway?

Comment: good point! unfortunately there's a hardware firewall in the front of the server (can't disable it on my own). So I just bound haproxy to an alternative port (8888) and everthing works fine with the same setup. So I'm quite sure it has something todo with the firewall messing around with port 80 ;)